# Rails concurrency and activejobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Here are some questions I have on ActiveJobs:

1. Say I've queued up n number of jobs on a job queue on sidekiq via ActiveJobs. On my EC2, I've set puma to have 4 workers, with 5 threads each. Does this mean up to 20 concurrent jobs will run at the same time? Will each thread pick up a queued job when it's idle and just process it? I tried this setting but it seems like it is still processing it in serial - 1 job at a time. Is there more settings I would need to do?
2. Regarding concurrency - how would I be able to setup even more EC2 instances just to tackle the job queue itself?
3. Regarding the queues itself - is there a way for us to manage / look at the queue from within Rails? Or should I rely on sidekiq's web interface to look at the queue?

Comment: Puma settings don't affect sidekiq at all. Sidekiq has its own concurrency settings.

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq has good [Wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/). As for your questions:

1. Sidekiq(and other Background Job implementations) works as [image: queued jobs]
   where `producer` is your Rails app(s), `Queue` - Redis and `consumer` - Sidekiq worker(s). All three entities are completely independent applications, which may run on different servers. So, neither Puma nor Rails application can affect Sidekiq concurrency at all.
2. Sidekiq concurrency description goes far beyond SO answer. You can google large posts by "scaling Sidekiq workers". In short: yes, you can run separate EC2 instance(s) and set up Redis and tune Sidekiq workers count, concurrency per worker, ruby runtime, queues concurrency and priority and so so on.
   **Edited**: Sidekiq has per worker configruration (usually sidekiq.yml). But number of workers is managed by system tools like Debian's Upstart. Or you can buy Sidekiq Pro/Enterprise with many features (like sidekiqswarm).
3. From wiki: [Sidekiq API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API)

Comment: Thanks for this - I was barking up the wrong tree after all. The wiki helps - still working on it, but will try further first before asking more questions on this. Again, knowing that all the configuration would be on the sidekiq side at least pointed me in the right direction. Cheers

Comment: @JoelLim Yes, Sidekiq has per worker configruration (usually sidekiq.yml). But number of workers is managed by system tools like Debian's Upstart. Or you can buy Sidekiq Pro/Enterprise with many features (like sidekiqswarm). Could you mark my answer as accepted if it helped you?